# Angular CLI version 7.3.3 not compatable with Typescript version 3.3.3333

Tags: angular, typescript, libraries

I was working off of typescript version 3.1.1 but after using yarn to import font awesome it updated typescript to version 3.3.3333.  This latest version of typescript cannot be compiled by the latest version of angular CLI (7.3.3).  Any ideas on how this can be solved?  If I install an older version of typescript it deletes the font awesome library because it must depend on typescript being version 3.3.3333.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Use Typescript 3.2.4

Comment: Maybe install older version of TypeScript and older version of FontAwesome (which will be compatible with that TypeScript version) ?

Comment: I tried using TypeScript 3.2.4 but my FontAwesome library disappeared from my node_modules library.  As well, since I am using Angular, I tried getting the FontAwesome library via the yarn command ( yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core ).  This provides an Angular library of FontAwesome which I can use, however I don't know how to get an older version of it.  Downloading FontAwesome from their github page does not come in an Angular library format.

Comment: Are you installing `font-awesome` (with a dash)? Or `fontawesome` (no dash). I've been using the former and not had problems with TypeScript versions.

Comment: I am unable to install font-awesome with a dash using yarn.  Thanks though.